# Are there known issues (in Feb 2018) with HTML5 Audio / Video in Chrome Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video, html5-audio

I am writing a web app where, at a certain point in the user interaction, a series of four `Audio` objects are played:

```
var myAudio1 = new Audio('/.my-audio-1.mp3');
var myAudio2 = new Audio('/.my-audio-2.mp3');
var myAudio3 = new Audio('/.my-audio-3.mp3');
var myAudio4 = new Audio('/.my-audio-4.mp3');

myAudio1.play();

setTimeout(function(){
    myAudio2.play();
}, 800);

setTimeout(function(){
    myAudio3.play();
}, 3200);

setTimeout(function(){
    myAudio4.play();
}, 3800);
```

followed by a `Video` object:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

setTimeout(function(){
    myVideo5.play();
}, 4200);
```

- The first `Audio` object plays
- The second `Audio` object starts playing just before the first finishes.
- The second `Audio` object is long and while it is still playing, the third `Audio` object and then the fourth `Audio` object plays
- Finally the video starts playing
- The second `Audio` object finishes playing either just before the video starts playing or just after

This setup works exactly as intended in:

- Firefox 58 on desktop
- Chrome 64 on desktop
- Firefox Mobile 58 for Android

But it **does not work** on:

- Chrome Mobile 64 for Android

Instead...

The first `Audio` object plays.

The second `Audio` object plays.

But neither the third nor the fourth `Audio` objects play.

The video loads (and can be started via user interaction) but it does not play programmatically on `.play()`.

I have been hunting for bugs for several hours and can find nothing. I have tried switching the Audio files around - always the first two play and then nothing else does. If I remove one or both of the first two `Audio` objects, it does not lead to the later objects playing instead.

---

It cannot simply be the case that Chrome Mobile won't respond to `.play()` - it already *is* responding to `.play()` with the first two `Audio` objects.

It also cannot be the case that Chrome Mobile will - unlike the other browsers - only play an `Audio` object if others are not playing - because there is an overlap at the beginning when object 2 starts before object 1 has finished.

So... what on earth is the issue that Chrome Mobile is experiencing that none of the other browsers are?

---

## Update 1

Ohhhh. That's interesting. It turns out Chrome Mobile *does* have idiosyncratic behaviour (compared to all desktop browsers and Firefox Mobile, at least).

It appears that `.play()` *will* launch the `<video>` if it is `muted`:

```
myVideo5.muted = true;
myVideo5.play(); // The video plays!
```

See: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay.

---

## Solution

The dynamically loaded HTML5 `Video` object will activate on `.play()` in all other browser contexts (Desktop Browsers and Firefox Mobile), but to activate the video on `.play()` in **Chrome Mobile**, include the following condition:

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') !== -1)
    && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobi') !== -1)) {

    currentVideo.muted = true;
}
```

**Result:** The video will play soundlessly in **Chrome Mobile** (awaiting explicit user consent to turn up the volume) and the video will play normally in all other browser contexts.

Comment: I think you would rather find help directly in the google-chrome devs forum or check for issues in the repository.

Comment: No, this should not work. The procedure that does work for Safari (and I hope for Mobile chrome) is to wait for an user gesture. In this event's handler, you will call a first `play` on all the elements that you will need to control later on, and as soon as they started playing, you will pause them. Normally (at least it works in Safari), the browser will mark these elements as allowed to be programmatically triggered, so you will be able to call `play()` later without the restriction.

Comment: Well Web Audio API could still help in this task (you could preload all the audio as ArrayBuffers and play them seamlessly with high precision scheduling, without restriction on the number of files to play). But anyway, if you don't have more than 6 media to interact with (which is the limit defined by specs), you may stick to MediaElements, but you will have to prepare all of them in the user-gesture event, and follow the procedure I already mentioned, whose main caveat is this 6 max simultaneous restriction.

Comment: I think the solution is to detect if the browser is Chrome Mobile and, if it is, to `mute` the video.

Comment: So I can confirm [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wv5vxsu/) works for me on Chrome for Android.

Comment: No, sadly this doesn't work. The video won't play if it's not `muted`. (This is why this is not a duplicate question). I will see if I can detect the Chrome Mobile browser using the methods outlined by MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) and then only `mute` the video for Chrome Mobile.

Comment: From what I am reading, I can  search the UA string for both 'Chrome' and 'mobi'. If both conditions are true then I can be reasonably certain that the browser in use is Google Chrome Mobile and I can `mute` the video.

Comment: The Solution: Video will activate on `.play()` in all other browser contexts (Desktop Browsers and Firefox Mobile, but to activate the video on `.play()` in Chrome Mobile, include the following condition: `if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') !== -1) && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobi') !== -1)) {currentVideo.muted = true;}`

Comment: @Rounin, don't forget to add the `@` when you want to ping someone. And to your issue, I am now 100% sure the solution I gave you (which is the one explained in the dupe target) does work on Chrome 64.0.3.3282.137 on an Android 7.0. I could both [replicate](https://jsfiddle.net/2wv5vxsu/1/) your issue and [workaround it](https://jsfiddle.net/2wv5vxsu/).

Comment: Solution above: The solution is to detect if the browser is Chrome Mobile and, if it is, to mute the video, using `currentVideo.muted = true;`